# What are the famous Demos on display in "The Stanley Parable Demo"?

Tags: the-stanley-parable, game-identification

In "The Stanley Parable Demo", there is a wall of four Famous Game Demos.  While I can easily recognize Half-Life and Metal Gear Solid, the other two escape my memory or knowledge.  What are these two games that feature on the wall, and do they hold any significance?

[image: "Famous Demos" wall]

Comment: The far left is Gunpoint. Dunno what the right one is though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. [Gunpoint](http://store.steampowered.com/app/206190), a recently-released indie game
2. [Metal Gear Solid 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Gear_Solid_2:_Sons_of_Liberty), the sequel to the famous Playstation stealth game. The pre-release demo was notable for being included with the game Zone of the Enders, which boosted the sales of the latter game.
3. Half-life: Uplink, the post-release standalone demo for the critically-acclaimed [Half-Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-Life_(video_game)), which included portions not available in the full game.
4. [Limits and Demonstrations](https://web.archive.org/web/20140320092130/http://indiestatik.com/2013/02/08/limits-demonstrations-kentucky-route-zero-devs-release-freeware-exhibition/), the demo for [Kentucky Route Zero](http://store.steampowered.com/app/231200)

Comment: I edited references to the MGS2/HL1 demos and added some notability...

Comment: They truly are famous demos!

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't identify them myself, so I searched the web a bit.

The games should be (from left to right); Gunpoint, Metal Gear Solid, Half-Life, and Limits And Demonstrations.

I found it in this post on reddit after a few minutes googling:
http://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/1o9ion/i_found_some_interesting_things_in_the_stanley/